# Confused by 'eq' in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What does 'eq' means in the following code? I have been learning Kotlin and it confused me!

```
fun main() {
val intSet = setOf(1, 1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 4)
// No duplicates:
intSet eq setOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 9)
// Element order is unimportant:
setOf(1, 2) eq setOf(2, 1)
}
```

Comment: Looks like an infix function but there is no infix function by that name in the standard library. You can read about infix functions in the Kotlin documentation.

Comment: In fact this is an infix function !! cf my answer

Comment: What exactly are you confused with? What does 'eq' means or what this 'eq' does? Does my answer gives  you enough understanding?

Answer (score -1):

**eq** here in as **infix** fuction cf here (https://stepik.org/lesson/104337/step/1?unit=88958 where it comes from: import atomictest.eq )

and it simply means equal.

This show that the **order** in a set is no important same as **duplicates**

Example with only duplicates and different order from https://replit.com/languages/kotlin:

[image]

Exemple with different order and not only duplicates:

[image]

more info here: https://stepik.org/lesson/104333/step/1?unit=78893

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, `eq` is the operator for set equality. It checks if both sets contain the same elements.

I tried your code on the Kotlin playground and it gave me the error: `Unresolved reference: eq`. To make it work, you would define `eq` as an [infix function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#infix-notation) , maybe like so:

```kotlin
infix fun<E, F: E, G: E> Set<F>.eq(other: Set<G>): Boolean = this == other
```